# How to cast a variable in Key Value Coding

Tags: objective-c

```
 [self setValue:flag forKey:variableName];
```

"flag" is a method's local BOOL; the keypath is also a BOOL member variable. But I get the Xcode warning `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion."

I also tried:

```
 [self setValue:(BOOL)flag forKey:variableName];
```

How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVC automatically boxes and unboxes non-objects. For the above case, you would use:

```
[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:flag] forKey:variableName];
```

See [Scalar and Structure Support](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html) in the Key-Value Coding Programming Guide.

Comment: cool, so it will set `variableName` ivar to the bool value of the NSNumber object, rather than trying to assign an  NSNumber object to the ivar?

Comment: In normal cases, it will call the setter after unboxing the BOOL. The setter typically is implemented as setting an ivar. The end result is usually the same as what you've said, but don't think of it as KVC modifying ivars. Think of it as KVC calling the setter. There are many cases where the difference matters. (There are some cases where it will actually set the ivar directly, but you shouldn't generally worry about those.) See the Key-Value Coding Programming Guide for full details.

Comment: thanks; in this case my BOOL ivar has no custom setter and is not a property. should I add a property when using KVC so there is a setter method?

Comment: You should always use properties. Avoid direct ivar access whenever possible. You generally shouldn't even declare ivars anymore; just let the system synthesize them for you when needed. This saves a lot of headaches.